# How to view long content in draggable div using scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have written code to make a draggable div. Result is: I can move the div around the screen, but I can't view the content inside the div using scrollbar. The sample code is:

HTML Code:

```
<div class="draggable"> 
<h2>This will drag the div</h2>
<div class="scroll">This won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag 

the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the div</div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.draggable').draggable({
                scroll: true});
    });
```

CSS Code:

```
.scroll
  {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

The problem is: When I try to scroll down to see more text, it also moves the div along with the cursor. That makes me unable to see the hidden content inside the div.

Jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/SswbX/90/

*Note: This issue only happens on Firefox Browser*

What I want is to view the contents inside the div using scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a div so as to have a **container** div and a **content** div and use **handle** option. This way the **scrollbar** will be applied on the **container** and the **draggable** will be activated only on the content.

Only problem is that without padding the scrollbar might overlap the content.

Something like this:

**Add a content div**

```
<div class="draggable">
  <h2>This will drag the div</h2>
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="content">This won't drag the divThis won't drag the divThis won't drag the div...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Add some padding to your scroll div:**

```
  .scroll {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-right: 15px;
  }
```

**Set handle to content and header:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.draggable').draggable({
    scroll: true,
    handle: '.content, h2'
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9j4rfLhL/5/

Comment: Awesome men! Thank you too much.